# How to cancel the Paypal Billing Agreement using REST API with PHP code

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

We have implemented "Billing Plan & Agreements" in our website as explained on http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/.

We have implemented weekly recurring payment and just want to cancel the billing agreement through the API.

Comment: It's on that link under the Billing Plan and Agreements, the "Suspend Agreement" option. [Details here.](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/SuspendBillingAgreement.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a object of Agreement & AgreementStateDescriptor and using object of Agreement call the cancel() method. Below is the code example using PHP.

```
        $agreementId = "I-ABACAGAH";                  
        $agreement = new Agreement();            

        $agreement->setId($agreementId);
        $agreementStateDescriptor = new AgreementStateDescriptor();
        $agreementStateDescriptor->setNote("Cancel the agreement");

        try {
            $agreement->cancel($agreementStateDescriptor, $this->_apiContext);
            $cancelAgreementDetails = Agreement::get($agreement->getId(), $this->_apiContext);                
        } catch (Exception $ex) {                  
        }
```

Comment: This does not work as subscription must be inactive first.