# PayPal PHP SDK not working for Subscriptions, get RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to use PayPal Smart Button to purpose payment on a website.

I first created a plan, I got its ID, and I activated it, via commands with the API and the PayPal SDK in PHP.

The plan appears to be active.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb-key&vault=true&disable-funding=card"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        env: 'sandbox',
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'P-85G86700MN...223CGEJWTI'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

When I click on the PayPal button to pay. I get this error: `RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`

I don't know what it all means, and people who have had the same problem have not received support.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) you are using should no longer be used for any new integration. It does not support the new Subscriptions API, and instead uses billing plans for something older, which is not compatible with what you are trying to do (RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND error is the result)

The new [paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK) can be used for regular payments (2022 edit: though it too may be deprecated now), but also doesn't support Subscriptions API.

So essentially, there is no SDK for subscriptions. To use the [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), you'll need to implement direct HTTPS REST API calls to first create the necessary product + plan, and then the 'subscription' (agreement-like object) is created and approved at checkout time. Alternatively, you can first create products+plans more simply via the account interface: [sandbox login](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans), or [live](https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans), which will also generate sample JS button code for a buyer to click and create/approve the subscription.

You could test with command-line `curl` or postman calls first, to confirm what you want to do works, and then write the necessary PHP function to do your own HTTPS calls to PayPal with the oauth token.

Oh and it's also possible to create the product + plan and (if desired) generate a corresponding button in the web interface of each account.

- [sandbox](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) accounts: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

Comment: "there is no PHP SDK for subscriptions" - It is **unbelievable** that one of the biggest payment providers does not provide this feature yet!

Comment: It might be that this could help (Billing Plan & Agreements): http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#billing ... Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42155987/1066234

Comment: That SDK is deprecated, and SDKs only exist for the one-time checkout and Payouts use cases; for everything else, PayPal's developer site now explicitly points to using a direct API integrations: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/deprecated-rest-sdks/